# count up from 0.00 to 176.20 with NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nstimer

I am working on an app and I want to animate the numbers in my app. I know I need to use an NSTimer. Just not sure how. For example I want the app to count up from 0.00 to 176.20 (self.total.text).

```
NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


- (void)update{
    float currentTime = [self.total.text floatValue];
    float newTime = currentTime + 0.1;
    self.total.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newTime];

}
```

Comment: There are countless examples of this. What have you tried so far? Update your question with some relevant code. What issue are you having?

Comment: Here is my code. I have it counting but it needs to count from 000.00 to the value of self.total.text. I have added code above.

Comment: Does 176 means 176 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide at what increment you want to count.  You want to stop at 176.20 so it seems like an increment of 0.1 seconds would be what you want. You need a variable to store the current position.

Obj-c///

```
const float limit = 176.2f

@property (nonatomic) float seconds;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *updateTimer;

// Initialize
self.seconds = 0.0f;
self.updateTimer = [NStimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
```

Swift///

```
var seconds = 0.0
let limit = 176.2
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("timerFired"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then you need to create a function which is used to update the label every time the timer fires and a function which schedules the timer.

Obj-c///

```
- (void)timerFired {
    self.seconds += 0.1f;
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.seconds];
    if (self.seconds >= limit) {
        [self.updateTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Swift///

```
func timerFired() {
    seconds += 0.1 //Increment the seconds
    label.text = "\(seconds)" //Set the label
    if (seconds >= limit) {
        timer.invalidate() 
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Please provide answers in the appropriate language.

Comment: And why not use a repeating timer? Simply invalidate it when you reach the end value.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I am still working with Objective-C on this project. I will see if I can convert your answer.

Comment: I added an obj-c version and updated the logic so it does not reschedule the timer but lets it repeat until the limit is reached.  I will tag Question as swift as well for anyone with a similar question in Swift.

Comment: Since timers do not fire exactly at the desired time, I would not increment but calculate the actual value from the starting time and now. Incrementing sums up errors.

Comment: For most cases, this is good enough, if someone wants to be super accurate ms timing across a long period, it would be worth it for them to do the extra work.